# Borrar un objeto de un array dentro de otro objeto e javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

```
var travelers = {
         familia1:[
           {name:"ana", lastname:"gomez"},
           {name:'jorge', lastname:'gomez'}
         ],
         familia2:[
           {name:"juan",lastname:"gomez"}
         ],
         familia3:[
           {name:"pedro", lastname:"gomez"},
           {name:'alfonso',lastname:'gomez'}
         ]
     };

function borrar(familia, indice){ //busco a la familia y elijo que indice quiero borrar del array
   for (const key in travelers) { //recorro el objeto de travelers
       if (familia===key) {          //comparo si es la familia que busco
           familia = familia.filter((i) => i !== indice);//quiero borrar a la persona segun el indidce
       }
   }
      //tendria que devolver mi nuevo objeto de travelers con las familias y sin el elemento que borre
}
```

> Quiero borrar ana gomez de la familia1 y que me devuelva familia1 solo con jorge gomez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu lógica es correcta, solo te falta saber cómo eliminar el elemento deseado, para eso se usa el método [`.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice), proporcionando el índice y la cantidad de elementos a borrar:

```js
var travelers = {familia1:[{name:"ana", lastname:"gomez"}, {name:'jorge', lastname:'gomez'}], familia2:[{name:"juan",lastname:"gomez"}], familia3:[{name:"pedro", lastname:"gomez"}, {name:'alfonso',lastname:'gomez'}]}

function borrar(familia, indice) {
    // Recorrer travelers
    for (const key in travelers) {
         // Si encuentra la familia
         if (familia===key) {
             // Eliminar elemento por índice, 1 = cantidad a borrar
             travelers[familia].splice(indice, 1);
         }
    }
    // No es necesario devolver un valor,
    // porque se está trabajando con el objeto original
}
borrar('familia1', 0);
console.log(travelers);
```

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes que borrar por el indice, la función `find` debe de recibir dos parámetros, el primero es el elemento y el segundo es el indice, por lo cual la funcion `find` quedaria mas o menos asi:

```
...find((el,i)=>i!=indice)
```

Posterior a eso, si tienes la `key` como "familia1" no es necesario hacer la búsqueda. toda la eliminación quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
travelers["familia1"].find((el,i)=>i!=indice)
```

Mira este ejemplo completo:

```js
var travelers = {
  familia1:[
    {name:"ana", lastname:"gomez"},
    {name:'jorge', lastname:'gomez'}
  ],
  familia2:[
    {name:"juan",lastname:"gomez"}
  ],
  familia3:[
    {name:"pedro", lastname:"gomez"}, 
    {name:'alfonso',lastname:'gomez'}
  ]
}
var indice=0;
var key="familia1";
console.log(travelers[key].find((el,i)=>i!=indice))
```

Lo único que faltaría es ponerlo en una funcion. Suerte .

Comment: hola, no me quedo claro aca como el find eliminaria ?, porque solo me tira el objeto que busco.

Comment: o tendria que poner esa funcion find en una variable y despues ponerla dentro del filter?